# How to Handle Offline Transactions in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an `addValueEventListener` which listens to any value changes in Firebase Realtime Database. In online mode, everything is working fine.

But in offline mode, device is offline and my Web Server has done multiple transactions on Firebase Realtime Database on same value for which I put the listener from Android. After the device comes online, it will only listen for the last transaction and skipping the other transactions done in between.

PFB reference [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-handling-transactions-offline). PFB code which i have done so far:

```
     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("mykey");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> key_Value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    for (String key : key_Value.keySet()) {
                        System.out.println("firebase key is "+key);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("feroz ", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Firebase doesn't store transactions. When you connect the database, you will get last values. So, you have to store every transaction in another node.

Comment: thanks for your reply but how can i append the data stored in node. in case of push each time it will generate new message id. i need a arraylist which keeps appending

Comment: can you add your database json to question(relative part of it)?

Comment: Push IDs are fine for storing a list of data.  They're ordered by timestamp.  See the documentation here under the heading "Append to a list of data".  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database stores information came back from an inquiry for use when disconnected. For questions developed while disconnected, the Firebase Realtime Database keeps on working for already stacked information. On the off chance that the asked for information hasn't stacked, the Firebase Realtime Database loads information from the nearby reserve. When we return online our information will stack and mirror the inquiry.

For instance, here we have a bit of code in our application that questions for the last four things in our Firebase Realtime Database of scores

```
DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
scoresRef.orderByValue().limitToLast(4).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
      System.out.println("The " + snapshot.getKey() + " dinosaur's score is " + snapshot.getValue());
    }
});
```

Comment: In realtime applications it is regularly valuable to distinguish when customers associate and detach. For instance, we might need to check a client as "disconnected" when their customer detaches. 
DatabaseRef presenceRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("disconnectmessage");
// Write a string when this client loses connection
presenceRef.onDisconnect().setValue("I disconnected!");